# ImageMagick convert - Label text over alpha background

Tags: imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert, alpha-transparency

I'm trying to place a copyright message on a large batch of PNG images. I'd like to place the message in the bottom-right corner in black text on a semi-transparent white background. Here's my Windows command line script which loops through the images and runs a ImageMagick *convert* & *composite* pipeline:

```
for %%f in (*.png) do (
  convert -background "#FFFFFF80" -font verdana -fill black ^
           label:" (c) 2015 My Company "  miff:-            ^
  | composite -compress zip -gravity SouthEast              ^
              -geometry +0+0 - "%%f" "credited\%%f.png" )
```

The white background with 50% (0x80) opacity is working well, but when the label text renders into the image, there's a horrible grey in the background of the characters. Here is an example by just running the initial *convert* into a PNG.

[image]

Is this a bug or am I missing something important in IM alpha channel management?

Comment: Which version does `convert -version` report for you?

Comment: I do not see anything being wrong with your approach. *(I took the liberty to re-format your command so it spans multiple lines to avoid horizontal scrolling. Hopefully I remembered correctly the `cmd.exe` syntax required for this... Otherwise just revert and/or correct it!)*

Comment: Try adding the `-matte` operator before `label:`. I half remember a previous thread about fonts and matte channel on older versions of IM.

Comment: I'm on 6.9.1-2 Q16 on x86 (2015-04-14), freshly downloaded today.

Answer (score 2):

Running these commands on OSX with version `6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64 2014-12-06`:

```
convert -background '#ffffff80' -font verdana \
        -size 360 -fill black label:"Hello World" hw1.png

convert -background '#00000080' -font verdana \
        -size 360 -fill black label:"Hello World" hw2.png

convert -background '#ff000080' -font verdana \
        -size 360 -fill black label:"Hello World" hw3.png

composite hw1.png -geometry +100+10 hw2.png comp12.png
composite hw1.png -geometry +100+10 hw3.png comp13.png
```

produces the following images:

[image: "Hello World"-image 1]

[image: "Hello World"-image 2]

[image: "Hello World"-image 3]

[image: hw1 + hw2 composite]

[image: hw2 + hw3 composite]

Comment: I'm going to try the same version on x86 and see it it works.